# Using a simple color shader in LibGDX

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, lwjgl

I've developed a render engine for a voxel based world which uses a really efficient rendering scheme. I've been able to use a specific color for the render by loading a new material. What I am having trouble with is loading a shader that simply makes the color look nice. I've done this before in LWJGL but I can't seem to get it with LibGdx. I've read all of blog.xoppa and clearly, shaders are what I am struggling with the most right now. Maybe I need some kind of SSAO shader or a deferredAO shader?

**Shader.frag**

```
varying vec3 position;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec4 color;

void main(){
vec4 ambient = vec4( vec3(abs(normal.x)*.8 + abs(normal.z)*.9  + abs(normal.y)*1), 1);

gl_FragColor = vec4(color) * ambient;
```

}

**Shader.vert**

```
varying vec3 position;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec4 color;

void main(){
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    position = vec3(gl_Vertex);
    normal = vec3(gl_Normal);
    color = vec4(gl_Color);
```

}

**My TestShader extends Shader, I have all the other implemented methods inside too. These are relevant.**

```
...
@Override
public void init() {
    program = new ShaderProgram(vert, frag);
    if (!program.isCompiled())
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(program.getLog());

} ...

@Override
public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {
    this.camera = camera;
    this.context = context;
    program.begin();
    context.setDepthTest(GL_LEQUAL);
    context.setCullFace(GL_BACK);
} ...

@Override
public void render(Renderable renderable) {
    renderable.meshPart.render(program);
} ...
```

What I *want* it to look like: (from before)[image: goingFor]
What it looks like with a **default Libgdx shader**, obviously I don't have multiple types of voxels per chunk yet but that is coming: [image: current]

Comment: Is this OpenGL ES or desktop OpenGL?

Comment: @NicolBolas Using libgdx for desktop so its OpenGl ES

Answer (score 0):

Alright I actually needed to use an SSAO shader which made it look nice and simple:

**FRAGMENT SHADER:**

```
uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

uniform vec2 camerarange;
uniform vec2 screensize;

float readDepth( in vec2 coord ) {
    return (2.0 * camerarange.x) / (camerarange.y + camerarange.x - texture2D( texture0, coord ).x * (camerarange.y - camerarange.x));  
}


void main(void)
{   
    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    //vec2 texCoord = texture2D(texture0, gl_TexCoord[0].st).xy;
    //vec3 texColor = texture2D(texture1, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;

    float depth = readDepth( texCoord );
    float d;

    float pw = 1.0 / screensize.x;
    float ph = 1.0 / screensize.y;

    float aoCap = 0.45;

    float ao = 0.0;

    float aoMultiplier=1000.0;

    float depthTolerance = 0.00001;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    pw*=2.0;
    ph*=2.0;
    aoMultiplier/=2.0;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    pw*=2.0;
    ph*=2.0;
    aoMultiplier/=2.0;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    pw*=2.0;
    ph*=2.0;
    aoMultiplier/=2.0;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    ao/=16.0;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.05 - ao) * texture2D(texture1, texCoord);
}
```

**VERTEX SHADER**

```
#version 110

void main(){
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

[image: change]